# Issues running the js Ipfs bitswap benchmarks

Tags: ipfs, js-ipfs, libp2p

I'm trying to do some performance testing of the js implementation of IPFSs bitswap. I've followed the instructions in the git repo here:

https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs-bitswap

But if I do an npm run benchmarks or 0x test/benchmarks/get-many

I just get the error:

'The dial request has no addresses'), codes.ERR_NO_VALID_ADDRESSES)

Following the code it seems I'm not generating a valid multiaddress.

Im sure this should be trivial and I'm probably missing something entirely obvious but can any one point me in the correct direction when it comes to running the benchmarks? Npm run tests works fine.